# Refresh iframe without refreshing the parent page

Tags: iframe, refresh

I have a page that constantly refreshes itself, I want to include the page into my main page.

I am using an iframe to include the page to my main page, but every time the page in the iframe refreshes, it also refreshes my main page. How can I make the iframe refresh within its own frame and not affect my main page?

Or is there a better way to include the page without using iframes?

Answer (score -1):

```
document.frames["myInnerFrame"].location.href=fl;
```

http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/15955-javascript-command-refresh-iframe-content.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1309969.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you need to refresh the parent page from asp.net code behind page, you can just register client script to run on page load:

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {   
        //Implement Your logic here.....  
        //..............................  
        //now refresh parent page and close this window  
        string script = "this.window.opener.location=this.window.opener.location;this.window.close();";  
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("REFRESH_PARENT"))  
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "REFRESH_PARENT", script, true);          
    }
```

The stepwise tutorial on [How to refresh parent page on child window close](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2011/07/refresh-parent-page-from-child-window.html) illustrates the use of the above function.